# A different method to send key presses to an application in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, keypress, sendkeys

I currently use this method to send keypresses to an application:

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("f")
```

In the past I've found this works no problem. Assuming the target application has focus this has worked for me in the past. Now, when working with a different application it's as if the key isn't being pressed. I have my vb.net application running with administrative privileges (the same elevation as the target application). Any help/links/code would be much appreciated.

Comment: How is the target application gaining focus?

Comment: initially by the user clicking inside it with the mouse. There's a 'thread.sleep' called before the sendkeys to make sure the user has enough time to click inside the target application.

Comment: Have you successfully sent keys to this application before? It could be that this particular application is listening for different messages (ie: `WM_KEYUP` instead of `WM_KEYDOWN`, etc).  I think `SendKeys` only sends `WM_KEYUP` in some circumstances.  You could test in the target application, if you don't have source, to see whether the action is triggered when you press the key or release it.

Comment: I've never sent keys to this application before. I'll try and run some tests and see what I can find out. Thanks

Comment: To be honest, you may have more luck moving on to a more modern framework than using `SendKeys`.  See : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx